# How to genuinely help someone when you have no skill in his department / specialty

Tags: ethics, helping

I've read here and there that you should be ready to give before you need something from others. In other words, help people before asking for their help.

I just asked a favor from a department in my company in a hurry, and even though the colleague agreed to do the task (I was smiling and somehow open to discussion, being polite etc.), I feel guilty about that.

I asked him if he could do it top priority, I didn't use the ticket-tool we have for this kind of request, and he accepted only because he is genuinely nice. All in all, I was extremely lucky I could talk to this guy in particular, his coworkers might not have accepted my request (which is normal - it's my fault if I'm late).

How could I have help him in any way, when his department is out of my technical background, without being rude or anything while asking for a favor ?

*Needless to say, if anyone comes to my office and ask for help I would immediately try to help him/her, or at least try to.*

**May be related:** [How do I thank a co-worker for helping me](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/34318/how-do-i-thank-a-co-worker-for-helping-me?rq=1)

Comment: Because using the tool would have take longer than directly ask "face to face". I was late (my fault), and knew my only option to have the task done for today was to ask directly and hopped for a preferential treatment... Wich I get.

Answer (score 3):

Helping before you receive help is nice but non-essential in my opinion. The more important thing is a genuine willingness to reciprocate the gesture. So at the risk of stating the obvious.. **ask him.**

There may be ancillary tasks in his department that he might need help with that you can do or there may be something in the future where he needs your skills. Either way or even if there is nothing you can actually do to help he'll probably appreciate the offer regardless.